# mySQL JOIN with specified keyword

Tags: mysql, sql, join

What is the best way to join 2 tables where the second table has an id and a keyword to join?

my try :

```
   SELECT id, name 
     FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id AND table2.id = 'myKeyword') 
    WHERE ...
```

Is there a way to handle the search / join of the keyword in the WHERE clause?

Comment: can you explain yourselft a little bit more?

Answer (score 2):

Placing `table2.id = 'myKeyword'` in the where clause will negate the `LEFT JOIN`

This is quite appropriate as you have it.

Maybe with a little more detail we can see what you are getting at.

Comment: Hi there, the thing is, that i want join the table also if there is no entry in table2, so i keep the result of table1. if i place the statement in the where clause, it gives me only the matched ones back.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT {column_list} 
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 
WHERE t1.id = t2.id 
AND {some_column_from_either_table} = 'myKeyword';
```